# Automatically switch my sound profiles based on Time/Location in Android

Tags: android, profiles

I would like to get some inputs in creating an application which will switch my sound profiles based on the current time.

For eg.
from 9:00am - 6:00pm -> Office profile(only if weekdays, else Home profile)
from 6:00pm - 10:00pm -> Home Profile
from 10:00pm - 6:00am -> Night Profile
from 6:00am - 9:00am -> Home Profile

How can we implement this?

Comment: Basically i dont have an idea on how i can do this, then how do you expect me to put the code..:-p

Comment: read about services and play with sound by setting volumes, etc.....